# Amazon Linux AMI: How to replace sendmail with postifx?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

Apologies in advance for my nub question.

Been using the Amazon EC2 Linux AMI and enjoying it.

It comes configured with sendmail. I think I'd rather use postfix.

I hoped replacing sendmail with postfix might be as simple as what I found searching online:

```
$ rpm -e sendmail
$ yum install postfix.
```

However rpm complains:

```
$ rpm -e sendmail
error: Failed dependencies:
        smtpdaemon is needed by (installed) mdadm-2.6.9-3.7.amzn1.i386
```

I'd be grateful for any guidance how to proceed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install `postfix` first, *then* remove `sendmail`. Or use `yum shell` to do both at once.

```
sudo yum install postfix
sudo yum erase sendmail
```

This will replace sendmail with postfix in your EC2 instance and will not remove other important dependencies when removing sendmail.

Comment: Or `rpm -e --nodeps sendmail`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to change default mail transfer agent, if you dont want to remove sendmail package and switch between sendmail and postfix.

"alternatives --config mta"